# Adding devise invitable not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I'm having User model (within PostgreSQL database) in my RoR application that's using Devise for authentication. Now I want users to be invited, so I decided to use [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) gem. Following the installation guide I did:

1. Add gem 'devise_invitable' to my Gemfile
2. Run rails generate devise_invitable:install
3. Run rails generate devise_invitable User

Than I tried to run the migration, generated above (it is the default one given by this gem and it looks like:)

```
class DeviseInvitableAddToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.string     :invitation_token, :limit => 60
      t.datetime   :invitation_sent_at
      t.datetime   :invitation_accepted_at
      t.integer    :invitation_limit
      t.references :invited_by, :polymorphic => true
      t.index      :invitation_token, :unique => true # for invitable
      t.index      :invited_by_id
    end

    # And allow null encrypted_password and password_salt:
    change_column_null :users, :encrypted_password, true
  end

  def down
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.remove_references :invited_by, :polymorphic => true
      t.remove :invitation_limit, :invitation_sent_at, :invitation_accepted_at,   :invitation_token
    end
  end
end
```

But, while running migrations, I get:

```
==  DeviseInvitableAddToUsers: migrating ======================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "invited_bies" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD CONSTRAINT fk_users_invited_by_id FOREIGN KEY ("invited_by_id") REFERENCES "invited_bies" ("id")
```

I am not guru in PostgreSQL and it's foreign keys, but it looks like there should be invited_bies table, should not it? But it is not being created. So, I'm a bit puzzled with this all.

My User model for devise:

```
devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, token_authenticatable,:trackable, :authentication_keys => [:email]
```

The fields `:invitable, :database_authenticatable` were added by the generating script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Schema_plus Gem?

If you are using it, this Gem will try to create a foreign key relationship based on the _id for any field.

You need to disable this for field like this

```
t.integer  :invited_by_id,  foreign_key: false
```

Let me know if this is the case.

Comment: Thank you! That's 100% correct. I'm on legacy project and missed this _evil_ schema plus gem. so, additionally to the the code you proposed I also had to add: `t.references :invited_by, :polymorphic => true, foreign_key: false`, because it (schema_plus gem) also wants to create ids for the 'reference' field too.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
3. Run rails generate devise_invitable
```

That should be

```
rails generate devise_invitable MODEL
```

and you replace MODEL with the name of your devise model. That is probably User, but it should be the name of the model that you are having devise manage for you.  So if you use User as your model:

```
rails generate devise_invitable User
```

Because you did not provide a model name, the generator is generating invalid migrations, which is probably a bug, and you might want to report that). when your migration tries to create the foreign key relationship between the invitation, and the "user" who made the invite "invited_by", it fails because it has no idea which table to reference.

Edit: 2013-05-04:

Does your User model also contain this:

```
 has_many :invitations, :class_name => self.to_s, :as => :invited_by
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not mention it, but I actually did use User model for migrations, thus you can see :invitable has been added to my User model.

Comment: Well then. I won't be able to help any further until this evening when I can get home and compare my set-up to yours.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it! BTW, I made it work (migration) by removing all stuff to deal with invited_by column, but of course this is not the solution.

Comment: No problem. I will either have the time between work and Bad Movie Night, or I'll get to it in the morning.

Comment: I added a question for you. Please see above.

Comment: Thanks for your help, do appreciate it. But my problem was with schema_plus gem, that I've missed.

Comment: That's an interesting looking gem. I'll have to check it out.